# API Token Safety in Angular application

Tags: api, angularjs, token

I'm building an Angular app with an API backend. On a combination of pieces of advice, I built the API with a flavor of token authentication. The flow is roughly as follows:

1. POST to login endpoint with credentials
2. Validate credentials and authorization, then generate a new token
3. Return token to client
4. Client uses token via HTTP Basic to access API resources

This is all working well. The problem arises in creating a session based on this token. I don't believe I should simply hold the token on the client in a cookie, but I do need a session to persist between page refreshes, etc. My Angular app is stateless and completely populated via API calls.

I'm looking for a recommendation as to hanging on to this token on the client. I feel there's danger in holding the token in a cookie because the cookie could be stolen and simply used to authenticate as someone else, but perhaps this is incorrect.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/20870386/2015318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its an Angular app, I'd assume all authenticated methods will only be served to ajax requests (you can tell your server to only respond to ajax) in which case CORS will help you.

The only way to be completely secure is HTTPS, however this method is probably more secure than you think. Read up on CORS a bit for more info, but essentially the idea is that servers will only respond to ajax requests coming from html pages that were served by that same domain.

Pre-flight OPTIONS requests are often sent to verify this. The browser sends an OPTIONS request with an Origin header (the origin of the page) before the actual request. If the origin matches the domain of the server receiving it, the subsequent request is allowed. Otherwise, it violates the Same Origin Policy and will be rejected.

This prevents someone from sniffing out the token and sending a request with the token from a page that your server didn't serve (like something running on the hackers local machine).

If you are doing credit card transactions or anything super secure, you should use HTTPS though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: HTTPS has been planned from the start. I appreciate the info on CORS; I will implement and then go with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only known way for me to identify a user is to use some token on the client.
HTTP is stateless and can't know which request is coming from which user (browser). You can't identify the user by his ip address (many users are behind a router and share a connection). You could try browser fingerprinting, it can work on some browsers but not on all.

I would recommend using a cookie to store this token on the client.
They are send to the server on every request and you can do some protection to keep them from getting stolen.

To protect this cookie from man in the middle attacks you need to use an encrypted connection over HTTPS to the server.

Set the following attributes on the cookie:

HTTPOnly: cookie can't be accessed by javascript (XSS protection)

Secure: cookie will only be send over https

Path: cookie will only be send on specified path e.g. /login

I would also define an expiration date on the cookie, so the cookie is invalid in like 2 days or something.

But you are right. If this token gets stolen someone else can login as this user.