# Are Angular apps with .Net Core Web API s vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a web app using Angular 7 and .Net Core Web API. I have implemented JWT authentication for my app. With these configurations, I need to know app is vulnerable to CSRF attacks. If it is vulnerable what are the implementations for the vulnerability?

Comment: there are different ways to manage CSRF, one is the use of cookies, another one is just by looking into the hosting and blacklisting some IPs

Comment: This is a vast topic to discuss, however [What if JWT stolen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259248/what-if-jwt-is-stolen/56578731#56578731) will give you an insight, when we talk about JWT

Comment: Thanks @JackM. According to my application architecture is my application vulnerable to CSRF?

Comment: maybe, maybe not depends on your implementation

Comment: @JackM I couldn't understand. Cant, we decide vulnerable or not?

Comment: no you can't hypothetically decide, like yanky_cranky said it's a huge topic for discussion refer to the link provided by @yanky_cranky and decide for yourself. Like I said it all depends on the implementation and not the technology