# set header in request to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, header

As described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445980/sessions-in-token-based-authentication) by Govind Samrow, using ajax setup to send every request with header to laravel by including:

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { "Authorization": "myValue" }
    });
```

However in my home page, there are anchor tag with href in order to **redirect user to other page**. Noticed that href is not allowed to attach header to top of that. The alternative way might be using XHR or fetch method.

I tried the XHR ajax but the purpose of XHR ajax mainly to stay on the same page instead of redirect to other page.

How can I attach header(with token value) to every href or buttons request to laravel and get verify by middleware? I struggling with the header attach part.

My middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
try {
    $token = $request->header('Authorization');
    if ($token) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        $response = array('success' => false, 'data' => null, 'detail' => array('message' => Messages::MSG_ERR_INVALID_TOKEN, 'error' => Messages::MSG_ERR_INVALID_TOKEN));
        return response()->json($response);
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $response = array('success' => false, 'data' => null, 'detail' => array('message' => Messages::MSG_ERROR_500, 'error' => array($ex)));
    return response()->json($response);
}
}
```

Comment: Are the routes that serve your pages in the `web` middleware group or the `api` middleware group? The routes that serve pages (web) shouldn't require an Authorization header because they authenticate with cookies.

Comment: hi @TravisBritz, the middleware is custom created and used for web route. I didn't register it under web or api group, just under routemiddleware.