# How to send JWT along with every request after successful login?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, jwt

I have a Node.js Express web application where a user can log in by posting his email address and password to a route `/signin` and when successful he receives a JWT token and stores it in his local storage.
I'm new to using JWT tokens for authorization and there's one thing I don't really understand how to do. How do I make sure that the user always send his JWT token with every request after a successful login?

I'm not using any front-end framework such as React or Vue.

Comment: Do you use a library like axios or jquery to perform these requests?

Comment: Nope. The request is sent directly from the browser by the user. For example, the user could request example.com/profile which should be protected. @JohnPapadopoulos

Comment: Have you considered storing the jwt in a cookie instead of localstorage?

Then it would be included in the request.

Check some resources on jwt storing methods too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817617/should-jwt-be-stored-in-localstorage-or-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the JWT in a cookie instead of in the local storage did the trick. Thanks to [@JohnPapadopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9990323/john-papadopoulos) for the suggestion :)

Comment: But reveals you to a CSRF attacks, so be careful of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to send HTTP headers on every *protected* requests. The *JWT* token would be carried by the *Authorization* header like so:

```
Authorization: Bearer efh1340ufeileaf3148913-your-token
```

Then your backend would check if the token is valid and not expired and grant access to the data/route etc.

Take a look at https://jwt.io/introduction/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication and many many more on the subject

Comment: But how would I set the Authorization header if the user requests the protected route directly from the browser?

Comment: _The only way to add headers to a request from inside a browser is use the XmlHttpRequest setRequestHeader method_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581383/adding-custom-http-headers-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jquery Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //Any CRUD Op
    url: 'url'  //the url to call
    data: datatosend,     
    contentType: contentType,           
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {   //Include the bearer token in header
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ jwt);
    }
},
success: function(){
    //Your success code
}
)
```