# How can we separate route of admin and user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am creating routes in `node js` . I am creating routes for dashboard.

1. User login and get the `JWT token`.
2. By sending Token,User can access some route related to user(edit,delete,logout route etc).
3. But For admin, I want to create the routes which can see the list of users,edit or remove users,check  the logout time of users.I have also set the flag in table to identify the person is user or Admin.

How will be authenticate routes for Admins on backend side?

Answer (score 4):

You can be inspired by this logic, And no further explanation can be given here. follow steps (It may help):

**First)** define `role` field into **DB** `mongoDB` or `Mysql` (for example):

```
enum: ['user', 'admin']
```

**Second)** create a function `checkRole(role)` for check role after signin and verify jwt, then get user

**Third)** create separate route for admin panel (for example):

```
router.route('/admin-panel').use(authController.checkRole('admin'))
```

Comment: but what is stopping `user` from becoming `admin` ?? a normal user can also choose themself to become as a admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your authorization flag in your JWT. When a user logs in, your server generates corresponding JWT, in which included authentication info(i.e. `userId`). You can put additional authorization info in the token(i.e. `auth`).

Based on the `auth` field, your server can identify whether the request is sent by a general user or an admin. Of course, securing the JWT from hijacking is an another story.

Comment: You mean to say implement the Basic Auth. Send the header with the request.Send (Authname and password) from the front end. Is it secure?

Comment: For storing jwt .I am using http cookie. Is it safe?

Comment: @Sharadkumar These posts - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27067251/2873538), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34817617/2873538) discuss safe storage of JWT / Auth tokens.

Comment: @Sharadkumar Speaking of sending password in plain text, you should do it via HTTPS connection.