# Confusions about "Authorization: Bearer JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN"

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, http-headers, bearer-token

I am a beginner using `jsonwebtoken` to authenticate a user in my node.js web app. I signed a jwt token in `app.post('/login')` using `jwt.sign()` and when i try to access/ verify it in `app.get('/dashboard')` using `req.headers['authorization'].split(' ').[1]` it gives null or `undefined` as there is no authorization header in `console.log(req.headers)`.

But it can be access or verify in postman as there i set auth type to `bearer <token>` due to which number of headers increment by 1 that is `authorization: bearer <token>`.

Then i store the token in cookie using `res.cookie('token', accessToken)` and i can access it in my routes without postman.

keeping in view above scenario i have following confusions:

- Where else can i store `jwt token` to access in my browser? and which is most secure store to access `jwt token` in browser?
- Why there is no `authorization: bearer <token>` header in my browser??
- Can i add `authorization: bearer <token>` header manually to access the token in my browser? if yes...how?
- If my app use `https` instead `http` protocol then will it be same situation of no `authorization: bearer <token>` header in browser?

I googled it but cant conclude. please help....!

Answer (score 0):

In **postman** you can add `token` field in header like [image: this]

```
key = token
value = token
```

and access it:

```js
let token = req.headers['token'] //token = 'token'
```

it is up to you if you add `Bearer` before token or not.

```
key = token
value = Bearer token
```

additionally **postman** have an **auth tab** that do exact thing.
it names key as `authorization` and for value it adds a prefix based on what you selected like `Bearer` and then adds it manually to `header`.
when writing client side cade, it is up to you whether to add `Bearer` prefix or not.

```
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  }
```

this is not related to `http` or `https`.
for how to use `jwt` in browser read:
[Should JWT be stored in localStorage or cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817617/should-jwt-be-stored-in-localstorage-or-cookie)