# Accessing Elastic Search indexes using Angular

Tags: python, angularjs, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am using python 2.7 for backend and angular js for the frontend. I am using AWS elastic search 2.3.3 which is active and the data is indexed. But when I try querying the indexes from angular I am facing the following issue.

[image: Issue]

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('jobgatorApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular-carousel', 'ui.tinymce', 'elasticsearch'
    //NO NOT TOUCH THE FOLLOWING LINE, IT IS SEARCH AND REPLACED BY GRUNT WHEN WE MINIFY THE JS
    ])

//TODO RESEARCH LAZY LOAD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184616/angularjs-lazy-load-template-and-controller-in-ui-router-requirejs-oclazyload
//TODO RESEARCH SECURITY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870386/authentication-with-angularjs-session-management-and-security-issues-with-rest
//TODO RESEARCH SECURITY http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-security-fundamentals
    .factory('elasticClient', ['esFactory', function (esFactory) {
        return esFactory({
            location: 'https://search-myjobgator-mkumzk6ax5z3ogumel2ga37bq4.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com',
            sniffOnStart: true,
            sniffInterval: 300000
        });
    }])
})();
```

Comment: Why do you want to query from the frontend, instead of providing an API from your backend (which queries ES and returns results to the frontend)? It's usually a bad idea to leave ES open to the world unless you absolutely have to...

Comment: yeah just shifted querying code to backend its working now thanks:)